# Django query - Sort by count of pair of generic relationship fields

Tags: django, generics, sql-order-by, relation

I have a model, Tic, that has a generic foreign key relationship with other models in my application.

```
class Tic(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'content_type', 'object_id')
```

I want to query this model and accomplish the following:

- Restrict to "Tics" over the past week
- Sort by occurances of (content_type, object_id) pairs (highest first)
- Be able to follow the objects that are returned (e.g. if a "Movie" object is returned, be able to do tic[0].content_object.movie_title)

So far, I have the following query which gets me the correct Tics, but I can only get it to work correctly as a list of values.

```
d = date.today() - timedelta(days=14)
t = Tic.objects.filter(added__gt = d).values('content_type','object_id').annotate(num_tic = Count('id')).order_by('-num_tic')
```

Any idea how to get a similar query to return objects instead?

**EDIT**

To follow-up, I was able to accomplish this by resorting to a raw query:

```
sql = 'SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tics_tic WHERE content_type_id = '+ str(movie_ct.id) +' GROUP BY content_type_id, object_id ORDER BY Count DESC'
```

Answer (score 0):

........just take out `.values`...

Comment: Currently "Count" only accepts 1 field. The .values('content_type','object_id') allows the count to numerate unique pairs of those two fields.

Comment: Unless I'm really misunderstanding what you're trying to do, why wouldn't you just have 2 order bys? First by content type, then by id?